# Find The Location of A Unique String Anywhere in Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, find, match

Like the title says, I'm trying to find the location of a unique string anywhere in an excel workbook.  It is guaranteed to be unique but can appear in any row or column of my table.

So for the example:

[image: Sample_Table]

I would want cell B7 to return B3 (the location of 5).  If I knew the column or row that it would appear in then it's a simple Lookup, Match, or Index problem.  I'm having a hard time finding examples where a value can be located anywhere in a sheet.

Comment: Have you tried using [Find & Select](http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/find-select.html)?

Comment: I need it programatically so that I can use the cell for other calculations.  I understand how to use ctrl + F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((A1:C4=B6)*ROW(A1:C4)),SUMPRODUCT((A1:C4=B6)*COLUMN(A1:C4)))
```

[image]

---

To return the relative reference `B3`, add `,4` to the end of the `ADDRESS` formula

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((A1:C4=B6)*ROW(A1:C4)),SUMPRODUCT((A1:C4=B6)*COLUMN(A1:C4)),4)
```

---

*Explanation*

`SUMPRODUCT` is an array formula. It accepts multiple arrays, multiplies them together and then sums the resultant array. In this case there is only one array, so it simply sums the values in that array without doing anything else with it.

Let's break down this array: `(A1:C4=B6)*ROW(A1:C4)`

`(A1:C4=B6)` looks like this:

```
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

and `ROW(A1:C4)` looks like this:

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
```

When you multiply the two arrays together, you get this:

```
FALSE*1 FALSE*1 FALSE*1
FALSE*2 FALSE*2 FALSE*2
FALSE*3 TRUE*3  FALSE*3
FALSE*4 FALSE*4 FALSE*4
```

Excel will treat `FALSE` as `0` and `TRUE` as `1` so the array will evaluate to:

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   3   0
0   0   0
```

Wrapping that array in a `SUMPRODUCT` formula will sum the values in the array and return `3`, which is the row in which `5` can be found.

Comment: this works perfectly.  Can you explain what's going on here?  On a low level I get that you are ending up with Address(3,2) which returns $B$3.  I don't understand the SUMPRODUCT functions.